# What exactly does the miner verify in the process of verifying the transaction?

Tags: solidity, transactions, mining, verify, contract-verification

I have seen different answers to this question. For example, one transaction calls a function on a smart contract. Some people say that the miner uses the same input to verify that the output is the same. Some people say that the miner does not verify the output, but only verifies that the contract is deployed correctly, interacts as expected with the network and follows the rules of the ethereum protocol.

I am very confused now and hope to get your help!

Comment: To validate a transaction you have to execute it and record all state changes to calculate the root of the patricia trie. If it matches the state recorded in the block header then it is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I am thinking about some extreme situations. If the api provided by chainLink is called in the smart contract, it is necessary that the contract address has enough tokens for payment. When the miner is verifying the smart contract, what if the contract address does not have enough tokens? Will miners continue to verify this transaction?